# Backup system, Raid 10

Tags: server, backup, raid

There is a server on which there is a hardware Raid 10 and 4 physical disks, an Ubuntu Server 20.04 system on which a website is running in Docker, I need to create a full backup of the system and then deploy it, I don’t really understand how I can make a snapshot of the system itself due to the multitude disks and not break the bootloader.

Here is my `lsblk` output, I will be grateful for any help.

[image]